# Markowitz and inverse covariance matrix

Tags: covariance, matrix, finance

Quite often in online literature it mentions that Markowitz CLA requires the inversion of the covariance matrix. In the python code samples I have seen displaying an efficient frontier and marking the Maximum Sharpe Ratio or Minimum Vol Portfolio - I have not seen the code inverting the covariance matrix - just dot products.

So my question is why does online literature say Markowitz requires the inversion of the covariance matrix when the code implementations do not invert the covariance matrix? If the inversion is necessary - where is it happening?

Comment: perhaps include the link of the code?

Comment: Hi: I don't remember the details but for some of the simpler mean variance settings ( i.e: long only say and no other constraints besides weight summing to 1.o ) , there are closed form solutions whose formulae involve the inverse of the covariance matrix. There should be a text that discusses these but I don't know of one to recommend. It's possible that Bernard Scherer may have written a text on portfolio optimization that discusses analytic solutions but I'm not positive.

Comment: Also, you may be better off asking this question on quant.stackexchange.com because it's more relevant to that list.

Comment: This thread looks very related to your question. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59202/derivation-of-mean-variance-portfolio-weights-as-closed-form-analytical-solution